# Comments and ratings on article page not visible to all users

Tags: publishing-page, social, content-rating

I have a strange problem regarding the SharePoint article page comments and ratings. I added the comments control and the ratings control in my page layout. The rating and comments functionality works fine, and i can rate and comment on article pages and afterwards see my ratings and comments.

My problem is that other users cannot see my ratings/comments, and I cannot see ratings and comments of other users.

I already manually started the 'Social rating synchronization job' and the 'Social data maintenance job' but there are still no other comments that are appearing.

Are there some other configurations or things I need to do to get this work?
When users only can see their own rating/comments, this functionality is a bit useless on my intranet.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,
Davy

Comment: I discovered something on this issue in the environment. It seems like it's a permission issue. The farm account can see the comments and ratings of all users. But this is the only account who can. The other accounts (even the site collection administrator) cannot see all comments. Someone knows if this can be an issue on database/service application level?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your problem still persists, but since I ran into the same issue I'll answer your question to help anyone else.

The issue is based Security Trimming in the field of Social Tags & Notes. You'll find several blog posts on this topic like [this one](http://sp2013.blogspot.de/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-social-tags-and-notes.html). It helped me to identify that I had to "Setup My Sites" which you can find under "Central Administration -> Manage Service Applications -> User Profile Service Application -> My Site Settings -> Setup My Site"

I changed the "Security Trimming Options" to "Show all links regardless of permission" which made the notes appear for all users, after the next crawl.

I'll update this post as soon as I find out:
- Why changing this trimming option helped, although I didn't have any links in my comments
- Where the permission configuration is located which causes the notes not to appear before. Social Notes have to be stored somewhere.